# Intermittent CORS Issue with WebAPI 2 after I added a DelegatingHandler

Tags: asp.net-web-api, cors, asp.net-web-api2

I've created a WebAPI 2 (Full Framework v4.7.x) as per the following fragment:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class MyTestController : ApiController
{
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GETSearchLatest20()
        {
            //etc...
        }
}
```

, where CORS is enabled by tagging each method with the `EnableCors` attribute as shown above

This has been working forever with no issues. Recently I introduced another handler into the pipeline, example fragment as follows:

```
public class CustomInterceptor : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected async override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        //...etc... logic here...
        
        //call the inner handlers...
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);

        //logs... etc 
        return response;
    }
}
```

Hereafter, I am now getting the dreaded blocked by CORS policy message **intermittently** on the Browser console.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8080/api/GETSearchLatest20/' from origin
> 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy:  No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.

Note I am running the server/WebAPI under Visual Studio.
I also don't understand the intermittent part; if I put a breakpoint on the line

```
var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

, the call proceeds to completion and there is no CORS error (it appears as if a little pause helps); If I remove the breakpoint, then the blocking message is intermittent.

Does anyone have any ideas / solution to fix my CORS problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've worked out what the problem was, the intermittent bug was due to the logic which I placed inside the `CustomInterceptor : DelegatingHandler`.

Adding the DelegatingHandler causes a pre-flight request, hence the `SendAsync` method executes twice in very quick succession (which I was not expecting, hence the bug). On the first call (pre-flight), my logic allowed the base method to be called

```
var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
```

, but on the second call (actual GET), my logic was returning to the client ("hey too many calls within a short period"), without proceeding to the above base method or inner handlers!

So the Browser reported this bypass as  `...has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'...etc`.